# copy file from local system to aws s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to copy file form my local system to aws s3 bucket using the following copy command:

```
aws s3 cp folder/ s3://xxx/yyy/folder --recursive
```

Only the smaller size files get copied but the larger file size (eg:5MB) files as are copying. I am receiving error like `connection reset by peer, write operation timed-out`.

I also looked for the link:

```
https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/634
```

But nothing works. Please help me to sort out this. Thanks in advance.

My version:

aws --version:

```
aws-cli/1.9.2 
Python/2.7.3 
Linux/3.5.0-27-generic 
botocore/1.3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following parameter

> --page-size (integer) The number of results to return in each response to a list operation. The default value is 1000 (the maximum allowed).
>   Using a lower value may help if an operation times out.

setting to 100 should help resolve your issue

Comment: whether i have to use this "aws s3 cp folder/ s3://xxx/yyy/folder  --page-size 100 --recursive" .

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use [Minio client aka mc](https://github.com/minio/mc) for same. `mc mirror` command can do this, it is open source. Minio client will take care of multipart upload natively and incase of network disconnection it will start uploading from where it had left before disconnecting.

```
$ mc mirror folder S3alias/folder
```

Feel free to check https://docs.minio.io/docs/minio-client-quick-start-guide for detailed information.

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I work for [Minio](https://www.minio.io)

Answer (score 0):

I am using the below AWS CLI version

`aws-cli/2.11.18 Python/3.11.3 Linux/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 exe/x86_64.ubuntu.22 prompt/off`

and used this command to upload a directory to s3 which has a 40 MB file

`aws s3 cp ./others-tmp/ s3://www.coolwebsite.com/my-website --recursive`

It is working fine. I think you need to update the AWS CLI version or there is something wrong with your network.

When you encounter errors like "connection reset by peer" or "write operation timed out" while copying larger files to an S3 bucket using the AWS CLI, it typically indicates issues with network connectivity or resource limitations.
Ensure that your internet connection is stable and not experiencing any disruptions. Try running other network-dependent tasks or tests to check if there are any issues with your network.